# Ubuntu on Flex 2-15

Tags: windows-8, laptop, touchscreen

I just got my new Lenovo Flex 2-15 with preinstalled Windows 8 using which I do not want to use.

I would like to install Ubuntu on it but I never had experience with touch screens and I am wondering if it is a good idea at all and if it will have a proper touch screen support or if not, any other Linux distributions that might have it? Are there any other driver problems like WiFi, for example, that may arise?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo Flex 14 (series 1), I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 8. For me, the touch screen works a treat, although I am old school and never have the need to touch it during normal use, I prefer to use the mouse and keyboard.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've a Flex 2-15 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed but I've a probem with battery. Its own details reports that it losts 6hr but in my case just 1 hr....and it's new. Lenovo's support saids that is a problem with Linux because they use some software to optamize the battery. I try to re.install Windoxxx and see if it's true or not

Answer (score 0):

When you asked this question, the answer would have been no. I was running only Ubuntu on this system with no issues. However I did have to reload Windows on here a couple of months ago and it upgraded to Windows 10.  After that, I was able to go back to Ubuntu with no need for Windows (happy dance).

Now, here is where the problems are starting to compound. The laptop would no longer just shutdown, it would power back on after 3 to 5 seconds. Also, wifi would stop functioning after roughly 15 to 20 minutes regardless of what the Ubuntu said. Restarting the network would have no effect. The only thing that I can think of is that there was an update to the UEFI.

I have tried many different flavors of Linux since then, Arch, Kali, Red Hat, Slackware, even FreeBSD in legacy mode. Same issue, wifi drops off after 15 minutes and is no longer useful. The only operating system that seems to work perfectly with this laptop is Windows 10.  Believe it or not, it was having issues with Windows 8.1 when I did a restore. I had to hardwire it to be able to update to Windows 10 again. So beware if you are planning on dumping Windows off this machine. It would be best to use a virtual machine and run anything other than Windows on top of Windows.  *shudder*